# I am working with a data set in Python and Pandas, I need to plot a horizontal bar graph

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxVxa.png)I need to do a horizontal bar plot. I have countries on one axis and I need to plot 'yes','no' and 'don't know' responses per country. However, there is no numerical value and I am trying to use Pandas to achieve this. So, how can I 'count' the three different responses and then have them be linked to each different countries and then plot them in a horizontal bar plot.

This is my code:
pd.DataFrame([dataFrame['Country'].value_counts() for count in dataFrame.columns]).plot.bar(stacked=True)

But I want to link a specific column with the country

Comment: Can you provide a sample df?

Comment: the df is quite big and I can't screenshot it.
How can i send a file?

Comment: No need to send the big file. Just a sample to know the structure. See my answer below.

Comment: So, how would I pick specific columns?
See my data has lots of columns to choose from. And I am only picking these responses from one column

Comment: use df[['col1', 'col2']].head()

Comment: This is my df.

Country               Welness Program

United States             Yes
United States              Yes
Canada                        No
United Kingdom           Not sure
United States                Not sure
United States                Not sure
United States                 Not sure
Canada                           Not sure
United States                   Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['iran', 'norway', 'us', 'iran','iran'], 'program': ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no']})
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('country')['program'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())).reset_index().pivot(index = 'country', columns = 'level_1').fillna(0).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

input df:

[image]

output:

[image]

Comment: okay.
This is what I got
pd.DataFrame([dataFrame['Country'].value_counts() for count in dataFrame.columns]).plot.bar(stacked=True)

Comment: That works for you?

Comment: no.
Because the count is wrong I think
I edited the original question with a picture of what I got.